# Regex to replace all matches unless the match is at the end of the string

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

I am currently using this regex to replace all non alpha numeric characters from a string and replace them with a dash

```
$newString = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9.]+/i", "-", $string);
```

This **works fine** for the following string.

```
$string = "this will work fine";
$newString = "this-will-work-fine";
```

**But** if the string has a non alpha numeric as the final character it will match and replace that, as one would suspect.

```
$string = "How can I fix this?";
$newString = "How-can-I-fix-this-";
```

How can I improve this regex to have the following output?

```
$newString = "How-can-I-fix-this";
```

The regex should work in **both** cases. I know I can just trim down the string with a separate function, but ideally I would like to use one regex. It this possible?

Comment: Most regex implementations will not allow you to define different replacement strings. You usually create a pattern, and then give a (single!) replacement string. So, the question is, what language (regex implementation) are you using?

Comment: I am using php's preg_replace function

Comment: What about the third case? When there is a non word character at the beginning?

Comment: @Salman - see my answer for a _one_ regex solution for the third case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're using PHP, you can define multiple patterns & replacements in one go. Here's a quick demo:

```
$string = "How can I fix this?";
$patterns = array('/[^0-9a-z.]+/i', '/[^0-9a-z.]+(?=$)/i');
$replacements = array('-', '');

echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string) . "\n";
```

which prints:

```
How-can-I-fix-this
```

Which is really nothing more than two successive replacements:

```
$string = "How can I fix this?";

echo preg_replace('/[^0-9a-z.]+/', '-', preg_replace('/[^0-9a-z.]+$/', '', $string)) . "\n";
```

Comment: I would almost use `/\W+$/` in the second pattern instead of using a look-ahead (though either work).

Comment: @BradChristie, yeah, that looks better.

Comment: `\W+` won't work. You have to use `[^a-z0-9.]+` with an `i` switch or `[^a-zA-Z0-9.]+`. `\W+` doesn't match `_` but does match `.`. This is not what the OP wanted.

Comment: And the fact that `\W` doesn't match `_` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to do this in two steps, because you have two different cases: At the beginning and in the middle of the string, you want to replace non alphanumerics with '-'. At the end, you want to replace them with the empty string.

Comment: This is what I was going to suggest.  Not everything has to be crammed into a single regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

You can always `trim("-how-can-i-fix-this-", "-");`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it *can* be done in one regex:

`$newString = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9.]++([a-z0-9.]++)(?:[^a-z0-9.]++$)?/i', '-$1', $string);`

**Note:**

- For future reference, `'-\1'`, `'-\\1'`, `"-\\1"`, and `"-$1"` are all valid alternatives for the replacement string.
- The possessive quantifiers are not really necessary in this case. However, I always use them even when the speed improvement is miniscule.

**EDIT:**

The third case (where the first character is non alpha numeric) can also be done with one regex:

`$newString = preg_replace('/(?:^[^a-z0-9.]++([a-z0-9.]++))?[^a-z0-9.]++([a-z0-9.]++)(?:[^a-z0-9.]++$)?/i', '$1-$2', $string);`

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working.. $string="will this work?"; evaluated to "will--"

Comment: @Alex - interesting. Did you try replacing all the `++` with `+`? I probably should have mentioned that I didn't test the regex in PHP, just in my text editor.

Comment: I am not testing in PHP, I am using an OSX regex application named "patterns". No luck with your most recent change

Comment: @Alex - I just tried the regex `[^a-z0-9.]++([a-z0-9.]++)(?:[^a-z0-9.]++$)?` with replacement `-$1` at [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html). Worked fine there.

Comment: I well check it out again and let you know. thanks for the help

Comment: @Alex - I just RTF(PHP)M :-) Turns out the quotes are _very_ important. `'\1'`, `'\\1'`, `'$1'`, `"\\1"` and `"$1"` are ok, but `"\1"` is the char with ascii value 1 octal! _That_ explains the "will--" result. I've now corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'How can I fix this?';
$string = trim(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', '-', $string), '-');
```

Replace all non alphanumeric with `'-'`, then trim from the ends.